# ¿Como agregar caracteres a una palabra contenida en un texto?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5

Necesitaba saber como colocar caracteres especiales a una palabra que seleccione dentro de un textarea. Por ejemplo, si tengo el siguiente texto:

**La palabra que deseo seleccionar es [esta] con corchete.**

Es decir, al seleccionar la palabra esta, se le agregue los [] en sus extremos.

Esto intentando algo así:

```
<form id="miform">
  <textarea id="texto" rows="20" cols="100">La palabra que deseo seleccionar es [esta] con corchete.</textarea> 
</form>

 <button class="btn btn-lg" type="submit" id="seleccione">Seleccionar</button>

 $("#seleccione").on("click", function (ev) {
  selectedText = document.getSelection();
  $("#texto").html("[ " + selectedText +"]");
});
```

Lógicamente se me va a reemplazar todo el texto por la palabra selecciona con corchetes, pero eso no es lo que quiero, sino lo que le había explicado.

Answer (score 0):

Esta sería una forma de hacerlo, solo faltaría ponerle los corchetes a la palabra elegida y no a todas las que sean iguales.

```js
$("#seleccione").on("click", function(ev) {
  let selectedText = window.getSelection().toString()
  let regexp = new RegExp(selectedText, 'g');
  selectedText=$("#texto").html().replace(regexp, "[" + selectedText + "]")
  $("#texto").html(selectedText);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="miform">
  <textarea id="texto" rows="20" cols="100">La palabra que deseo seleccionar es esta con corchete.</textarea>
</form>

<button class="btn btn-lg" type="submit" id="seleccione">Seleccionar</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Buenas esta forma sería afectando solo a el texto seleccionado. Espero que te sirva

```js
function markSelection(el) {
  const {
    selectionStart,
    selectionEnd,
    value
  } = el;
  const to = selectionEnd - selectionStart;
  const selectedText = '[' + value.substr(selectionStart, to) + ']';
  const prevToSelection = value.substring(0, selectionStart);
  const nextToSelection = value.substring(selectionEnd);
  el.value = prevToSelection + selectedText + nextToSelection;
}
```

```css
#text {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipiscing elit mattis nisi nunc, vehicula tristique proin commodo. Fermentum ante sociosqu torquent posuere montes cursus tincidunt massa pellentesque donec arcu, etiam convallis varius lobortis mollis cras pharetra scelerisque nullam mus leo fames, tempor vel elementum odio porta nisl lectus nisi parturient a. Nam iaculis felis vehicula massa auctor sodales lacinia, sagittis a augue malesuada natoque netus penatibus phasellus, at ut vulputate rutrum diam quis.

Praesent erat tempus aenean porta laoreet hac, facilisi ultricies litora inceptos sed etiam maecenas, senectus ornare torquent penatibus viverra. Maecenas leo condimentum rutrum cubilia ac sociosqu habitasse aliquet, urna lacinia tristique rhoncus morbi curabitur praesent, felis dapibus accumsan sagittis sem auctor fusce. Taciti hendrerit tincidunt urna tristique aenean mauris tempus metus, convallis massa neque platea semper aptent sem, felis id odio conubia molestie in erat.</textarea>
<button onclick="markSelection(text)">Marcar seleccion</button>
```